# VBA to VLOOKUP a value from a pivot table to return value in multiple columns in the output sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, one is sheet `Data Sheet` with a pivot table with data of different companies. I have another sheet `Output Sheet` with few column headings from data sheet, I want to `vlookup` different column headings using the Company ID. I have found the below code and it works fine for mapping company name but has the following issues

1. The formula runs till 100000 rows even if the `companyID` is available only till 9555 row, and there after displays `#N/A`
2. How to make this formula lookup other column headings like Segment, Sector Etc.

Columns Heading that needs to be mapped:

[image]

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
    Dim SourceLastRow As Long
    Dim OutputLastRow As Long
    Dim sourceBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Where is the source workbook?
    Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\NewFolder\Automation\07-Macro.xlsb")

    'what are the names of our worksheets?
    Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("TERFYTDPR")
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All TMS-Data")

    'Determine last row of source
    With sourceSheet
        SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With outputSheet
        'Determine last row in col B
        OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Apply our formula
        .Range("B2:B10000" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
            "=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
        OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    'Close the source workbook, don't save any changes
    sourceBook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know the layout of your data on the Worksheet you are doing the Vlookup against, but just thought I would explain the Vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
```

The last number 2 on the line of code above refers to the column number you would like to return if the Contents of A2 match, you can alter this to get another column number, such as 3 for the third column, but you should also change the range to lookup from $A$2:$B$, to include the other columns.

So for example if your Segment column is in Column C, you would alter your vlookup as such:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$C$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0)"
```

I would also re-write your code as follows:

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long, OutputLastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Where is the source workbook?
Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\NewFolder\Automation\07-Macro.xlsb")

'what are the names of our worksheets?
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("TERFYTDPR")
Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All TMS-Data")

'Determine last row of source
SourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Determine last row in col B
OutputLastRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Apply our formula
For i = 2 To OutputLastRow
    outputSheet.Range("B" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & i & ",'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$C$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
    outputSheet.Range("C" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & i & ",'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$C$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0)"
'if segment is found in column C, and you also want the results in column C the line above will return the desired value
Next i
'Close the source workbook, don't save any changes
sourceBook.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To do the same without a loop:

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long, OutputLastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Where is the source workbook?
Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\NewFolder\Automation\07-Macro.xlsb")

'what are the names of our worksheets?
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("TERFYTDPR")
Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All TMS-Data")

'Determine last row of source
SourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Determine last row in col B
OutputLastRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Apply our formula
outputSheet.Range("B2:B:" & OutputLastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$C$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
outputSheet.Range("C2:C" & OutputLastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$C$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0)"
'if segment is found in column C, and you also want the results in column C the line above will return the desired value

'Close the source workbook, don't save any changes
sourceBook.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Xabier,i had initially put "B2:B, but the formula is appearing only in the row B2, then i increased the range from B2:B1000 but it keeps extending to some other row number, it doesnt extend till the last row of the sheet

Comment: its not working, but the code you posted before this edit was working well but except with the #N/A issue

Comment: sorry again, now the excel is taking too much time to respond, the code you posted second was very quick and almost solved the issue except the #N/A

Comment: Now it gives a runtime error :-(, could you try the very second edit you have made, that almost solve the issue :-)

Comment: @Venus, I've posted the previous version again after Update, hopefully it should work now....

Comment: @VenusJain, is the workbook `07-Macro.xlsb` open when you run the code? As the code itself opens the workbook, it could be the reason for the error...

Comment: the run time error is at this point : outputSheet.Range("B2:B:" & OutputLastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & sourceBook.Name & "]" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$C$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to populate the `VLOOKUP` formula into the table but only for the rows where is a data?

Assuming that Column "A" - CompanyID and "B" - Company Name is always populated and there are no gaps between the records you can make excel to drag the formula for you

Here is the code for you

```
Sub test()

Dim maxRow As Long
Dim DataWS As Worksheet
Dim lookupWS As Worksheet

'Set your data sheet
Set DataWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
'Set your lookup sheet
Set lookupWS = Worksheets("Sheet2")

maxRow = lookupWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'Populate formula
'Company Name
lookupWS.Range("B2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2," & DataWS.Name & "!$A:$F,2,FALSE)" 'Make sure you change "2" to correct value in your case
'Segment
lookupWS.Range("C2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2," & DataWS.Name & "!$A:$F,3,FALSE)" 'Make sure you change "3" to correct value in your case
'Sector
lookupWS.Range("D2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2," & DataWS.Name & "!$A:$F,4,FALSE)" 'Make sure you change "4" to correct value in your case
'Channel
lookupWS.Range("E2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2," & DataWS.Name & "!$A:$F,5,FALSE)" 'Make sure you change "5" to correct value in your case
'Account Type
lookupWS.Range("F2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2," & DataWS.Name & "!$A:$F,6,FALSE)" 'Make sure you change "6" to correct value in your case

'Drag formula
Range("B2:F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:F" & maxRow), Type:=xlFillCopy


End Sub
```

Make sure you change your `range` arrays appropriately and it should work for you.

Comment: my source data is a pivot and is present in another workbook